# Efficient Hierarchical Reference parsing in XSLT

Tags: xml, algorithm, xslt

I have thousands of data objects in my file. There are references (@refid contains value of @id of referenced object) between them. I'd like to draw a diagram illustrating the relationships in a digraph, as shown below.

[image: Digraph showing relationships between data objects]

My current algorithm works, but takes multiple passes. Starting from the first node ("Improved Sunder" here) it finds all references to each node until it hits dead ends ("Crushing Disarm", "Greater Hinder Natural Attack", and "Hinder Special Ability", "Impede Movement", and a number of shorter chains), then works its way back, following the references until it hits the earlier terminators. Each node touched on the way back gets output. This means that each of my original data objects might be included multiple times in the output ("Combat Expertise" is a prerequisite to three of the objects show, which causes it to be included in the output three times). Where possible I cull the relationships ("Crushing Disarm" explicitly references both "Improved Disarm" and "Combat Expertise", but because "Crushing Disarm" explicitly references "Improved Disarm" and "Combat Expertise" I can cull the link between "Combat Expertise" and "Crushing Disarm").

(Incidentally, the dot program from GraphViz is an awesomely useful tool at times. Not only does it do the layout for me -- I'll be drawing a prettier version of this later, but for a first-pass automated image this looks good enough -- it is smart enough to realize these multiply-defined objects are the same thing and equate them.)

I have another task that needs the unique list of nodes and edges. I can get it by doing a second pass (another transformation on the output from the first) that uniques them, but I wonder if there is a way to do it in a single step.

Comment: It would help if you could clarify your question, preferably by including code.  But it sounds like you are thinking somewhat procedurally.  Remember XSLT and XPath are functional languages.  Try to describe the sets you want to collect in terms of their "static" relationships (i.e., looking at the whole picture at once).  See if you can express them as constraints, without using the word "then".  This usually helps clean up traversal expressions.

Comment: I do plan to include code... but my existing code is based on the last schema of the input data, and thus produces bogus output. I'm updating it now.

Comment: I don't know if I can identify the nodes by constraints. The base input is a little dodgy when it comes to identifying relationships, and might mention only the immediate relationships ("Crushing Disarm" might mention only "Improved Disarm", "Improved Unarmed Strike", and "Improved Sunder"), and it's up to me to identify from those identified objects that I need to also pull in "Combat Expertise" and "Power Attack".

Comment: Mind you, that might be the answer -- it's not an algorithm problem, I need to improve my input data. For each input object follow all the links down and make them explicit prerequisites (add references to the second-and-further prerequisites). Then later I can simply say "find everything that has this as a prerequisite, and all of my prerequisites, _done_". Mind you, this might still have the uniquing problem (A depends on B and C, B and C each depend on D; I don't really want to have D in the list twice... and it's even uglier when A depends on B _or_ C, each of which depends on D).

Comment: You mentioned doing a preliminary transform.  It sounds now like that's worth a try.  Personally, I find that kind of decomposition helps.

Comment: I have to think about it. In the absence of information I haven't said, it is exactly the solution because it resolves data discontinuity. However, there is a complication: sometimes you can meet a prerequisite but its prerequisites are waived. Imagine an F that needs D, which needs B and C, but B and C are not explicitly mentioned in F. If I can get D without getting B and C (and there are situations in which this can happen) then I should be able to take F without B and C (rules as written). If the data is changed to fill in the implied links that invalidates the existing rules.

Comment: Right... the intermediate structure would be used only by the algorithm, which it would be designed to serve.  Your actual storage format would not need to change, you're just refactoring the algorithm to chain two transforms.  Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Nope, that's what it's doing. I'm still doing two transformations, but one leads to a more ~~exhaustive~~ _robust_ data set that makes the next step easier. And I just realized, if I want to make it even more robust then after I work out what the initial relationships are I create a second one in parallel that is marked "robust" and can be used to not only easily do this kind of mapping, but could help me with other similar tasks... but I continue to display only exactly what I was presented originally.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you're trying to compute a [transitive reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) on the acyclic directed graph of prerequisites. I would suggest gently that you not try to use XSLT for this unless you want a challenge; I haven't found a declarative language that feels comfortable for implementing nontrivial graph algorithms efficiently.

Comment: That's the second part of what I'm doing, and by and large it has not proven very difficult, at least for the data I have. harpo's suggestion makes it even easier -- by identifying all the things that eventually lead to each node, I first do the opposite of a transitive reduction (in the diagram in the wiki link you provided, I add a link from B to E, so I can readily identify that B can reach E without taking other steps). The transitive reduction then amounts to "if A and B both point at E, and A points at B, I can remove the link from A to E because that is still reachable via B".

Comment: So I can identify the nodes uniquely to be included in the diagram (for object N find all objects with prerequisites that point at N), find all objects that are prerequisites of those, unique the results, and output each node. For each node examine the prerequisites, and if the current prerequisite is not also prerequisite of another prerequisite (a little hinky, I'd have to look up the XQuery I used on this one) output the edge definition.

Comment: The bigger question was how to get a good initial set of nodes, preferably in one pass. I think I can't, quite, without the transitive anti-reduction. I'd already solved my transitive reduction, before I found out it was hard :)